# What happened to the possessive form, its'?

Tags: punctuation

When I was young, the possessive form of the word, it, required an apostrophe preceded by an S. An example our teacher used, which I've always remembered, was: "It's my work but I am its' property, rather than the reverse, by virtue of how essential the work has become."

Over several years, however,  I've seen the trailing apostrophe almost totally removed from usage.  When and why did that rule change?

Comment: If this is in fact what you were taught, you were mistaught. Possessive *its* has never been spelled *its'*, and the occasional variant spelling *it's* was ceded to the contraction by the 18th century.

Comment: Do you also want to use *his'*, *hers'*, and *their's* ??

Comment: Why not? It at least makes sense. Fads in teaching the deployment of inaudible and randomly distributed punctuation come and go. If a teacher decided that it ought to be rationalized, well, that's what teachers are for, isn't it? Nothing unusual here. @Mark, it does seem to be nonstandard, but if you've got this far in life without its' affecting you, you might as well go right ahead and continue. After all, it's **your** language.